# Why can |= do in-place value update for dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So here is the code

```
tmp_dict = {}
x = tmp_dict.setdefault("key1", set())
x |= {1,2}  
tmp_dict
```

And the output is

```
{'key1': {1, 2}}
```

But if we change the 3rd line to
`x = x | {1,2}`
then the output would be

```
{'key1': set()}
```

So I am curious why `|=`  does such magic here that the dictionary gets updated. I thought `x = x | {1,2}` and `x |= {1,2}` would be equivalent but actually they are not.

Comment: `|=` modifies the set in place, `=` reassigns the variable without modifying the set.

Comment: Most of the container types overload the `<operator>=` operators so they do in-place modification.

Comment: The dictionary is irrelevant. You'd see the same difference if you simply did `x = set()` and `y = x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `|=` references `__ior__`, but `|` references `__or__`.

`|=` will modify the original `x` object, which would effect the `tmp_dict`, but modifying `x = ..` would override `x` completely so that the reference to `tmp_dict` would be gone.

It would just create a variable named `x` with the union of the sets.